# Call asmx webservice from MVC view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, web-services

People, I'm trying to call an asmx service from an MVC view.

The code in asmx looks like:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ToolboxItem(false)]
[ScriptService]
public class MyService : WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string SomeMethod()
    {
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

the ajax call in the mvc view is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "MyService.asmx/SomeMethod",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert('error: ' + e.msg);
        }
    });
});
```

But i'm always getting an 'undefined' error.  With fiddler enabled i figured out that the webservice couldn't be found (The resource cannot be found).

Any help appreciated

EDIT:

Ok, i got it working.  I needed to add following line to my RouteConfig:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*x}", new { x = @".*\.asmx(/.*)?" });
```

Comment: I've tried everyting, nothing works.  It must be something stupid.  If i type http://localhost:58324/myservice.asmx i see the service but when i click the SomeMethod i get a 404.